# PHPUnit - Command-line test drops down a line for no apparent reason?

Tags: php, phpunit

Normally the PHPUnit command-line runner gives output similar to following:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

....

Time: 26 seconds, Memory: 10.00Mb

OK (4 tests, 84 assertions)
```

However, in one of my tests the following occurs:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.
...

Time: 26 seconds, Memory: 10.00Mb

OK (4 tests, 84 assertions)
```

It has something to do with one of the fixtures that's included. If I comment out the correct fixture this oddity does not show up. However, I've tried removing every part of the code in the fixture file itself and this still happens. It's not related to the first test. This happens regardless of which test is moved to the top of the test file. So it must be something with the model of the fixture itself. Yet, nothing stands out to me as being the culprit. It doesn't actually seem to affect the test in anyway, but it bothers me that this is happening anyway. Anyone have any suggestions/seen this before? Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in your 2nd test outputs a carriage-return. I can reproduce your output with this simple file:

```
<?php
class EchoTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

function test1(){ $this->assertEquals(3,1+2); }
function test2(){ echo "\n";$this->assertEquals(3,1+2); }
function test3(){ $this->assertEquals(8,3+5); }
function test4(){ $this->assertEquals(11,5+6); }
}
```

If you don't see any obvious echos, and your tests are in multiple files, the classic cause would be a stray blank line before `<?php` or after the closing `?>`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to come back here to say I already found the answer. But yes it was stray blank line after the closing "?>". And don't worry, I already know that the closing tag is "optional". Thank you much!